# Ubuntu 10.04 won't mount USB hard drive (not even in /dev)

Tags: hard-drive, usb, ubuntu-10.04

I just installed Ubuntu 10.04 and my SD card reader and my USB hard drive are not recognized. My USB tablet (Wacom Bamboo) works fine.

I checked dmesg and it seems that the USB driver has found the device. Note that I disconnected the device and reconnected it to make sure that the "new high speed USB device" was the USB hard drive.

```
josh@Nadie:~$ dmesg | tail
[  601.142564] EXT3-fs: mounted filesystem with ordered data mode.
[  606.421382] kjournald starting.  Commit interval 5 seconds
[  606.421411] EXT3-fs: mounted filesystem with ordered data mode.
[  606.996796] kjournald starting.  Commit interval 5 seconds
[  606.996867] EXT3-fs: mounted filesystem with ordered data mode.
[ 1310.374797] usb 2-1.3: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 5
[ 1310.496847] usb 2-1.3: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[ 2040.963946] usb 2-1.3: USB disconnect, address 5
[ 2052.971000] usb 2-1.3: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 6
[ 2053.083204] usb 2-1.3: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
```

And when I try 'lsusb', I also see the hard drive listed (Western Digital):

```
josh@Nadie:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 1058:1010 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0a5c:5800 Broadcom Corp. BCM5880 Secure Applications Processor
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 056a:0018 Wacom Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

But nothing gets listed in `/dev`:

```
josh@Nadie:~$ ls -l /dev/sd*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 2010-07-05 22:07 /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 1 2010-07-05 22:07 /dev/sda1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 2 2010-07-05 22:07 /dev/sda2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 3 2010-07-05 22:07 /dev/sda3
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 4 2010-07-05 22:07 /dev/sda4
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 5 2010-07-05 22:07 /dev/sda5
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 6 2010-07-05 22:07 /dev/sda6
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 7 2010-07-05 22:07 /dev/sda7
```

Note that `sda` is the main hard drive that Ubuntu is installed on. I read on Linux forums that maybe certain kernel modules were missing, but I don't know what they would be called, so I tried lsmod and grep'ed for "usb":

```
josh@Nadie:~$ lsmod | grep -P .*usb.*
usbhid                 40988  0 
hid                    83376  1 usbhid
```

I'm not sure what else to do to debug the issue.

(This question is also [posted at UbuntuForums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1524890).)

---

In response to the first answer by ignacio-vazquez-abrams:

```
josh@Nadie:~$ modprobe usb-storage
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-21-generic/modules.dep: No such file or directory
josh@Nadie:~$ sudo modprobe usb-storage
[sudo] password for josh: 
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-21-generic/modules.dep: No such file o
```

---

Edit:

Doh. That was dumb. I was accidentally booting into 2.6.32-21, when I had upgraded to 1.6.32-23, and already removed -21.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module you're looking for is `usb-storage`. Try probing it and inserting your devices after.

```
modprobe usb-storage
```

Comment: Ok, that worked. The next time I rebooted the USB drive mounted without my doing anything. I'm not sure what the "real" problem was, booting with the wrong kernel or whatever, but in any case... problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Linux Mint Maya here!
My USB sticks were mounting fine until some day they became ''root''. Reading tips here and there I removed ''usbmount'' with Synaptic. My stick became mine without any other effort. hope it is useful.